# Exponential operator acting on a product of functions

Tags: derivatives, operator-algebras, differential-operators

An operator $\exp \left(\tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)$ when acting on a function $f(x,t)$ can be show to satisfy the following equation:

$$ \exp \left(\tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right) f(x,t) = f(x,t+\tau)$$

This can be done by expanding the exponential operator as a Taylor series $(1 + \tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \frac{\tau^2}{2!}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} + ...)$ and applying it on the function $f$ to give $\left(f(x,t) + \tau\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,t)+ \frac{\tau^2}{2!}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} f(x,t) + ... \right)$. 
This is simply the Taylor expansion of $f(x,t+\tau)$.

If however, the function $f$ is a product of two function $g=g(x,0)$ and $h=h(x,0)$, would the following relation hold?

$$ \exp \left(\tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right) \left[g(x,t) h(x,t)\right] = g(x,t+\tau) h(x,t+\tau)$$

How would I go about proving or disproving this?

Comment: What makes you think that it would not hold?

Comment: Expanding the operator and substituting $g(x,0)h(x,0)$ in place of $f(x,0)$ gets hard to simplify because of the product rule of the differential.
Also you get terms with derivatives of both $g(x,0)$ and $h(x,0)$ together which are hard to separate.

Comment: Yes, expanding it becomes complicated, but your question was: *would the following relation hold?*. I see no reason why it would not, hence no need to expand it.

Comment: I would still like to prove it. Would you have any advice about how to proceed to do that?

Comment: But what is there to prove? If you know that an equality holds for $f$ in general, then it will hold regardless if $f$ is a product or a sum or a composition etc.

Comment: Or maybe I am misunderstanding your question?

Comment: It's not intuitive to me that the result would hold. For instance, another (seemingly reasonable) answer could be $g(x,0)h(x,t) + g(x,t)h(x,0)$.
I appreciate your patience.

Comment: But if you know that $\exp(t \partial_t) f(x,0) = f(x,t)$ holds for all functions $f$, then why would it not hold for $f(x,t) = g(x,t) h(x,t)$ in particular?

Comment: You can get proper parentheses that adjust to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments, a function is still a function when you write it as a product. If you've proved a result for all functions, then it holds for all functions, including functions that you happen to write as a product. Note that all functions can be written as a product: $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $g(x)\equiv1$ and $h(x)=f(x)$.

There are two errors in your presentation and derivation of the exponential operator result. First, $f(x,0)$ doesn't depend on $t$, so $\exp\left(t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)$ annihilates it. Second, $t$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ don't commute, so you can't reorder them like you did.

The correct relationship is

$$
\exp\left(\tau\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\,f(x,t)=f(x,t+\tau)\;.
$$

*Edit*:

Taking the long way home:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\exp \left( \tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) (gh)
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left( \tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)^n(gh)
\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\tau^n}{n!}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial t^n}(gh)
\\
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\tau^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{\partial^kg}{\partial t^k}\frac{\partial^{n-k}h}{\partial t^{n-k}}
\\
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\tau^k}{k!}\frac{\partial^kg}{\partial t^k}\frac{\tau^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{\partial^{n-k}h}{\partial t^{n-k}}
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{\tau^k}{k!}\frac{\partial^kg}{\partial t^k}\frac{\tau^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{\partial^{n-k}h}{\partial t^{n-k}}
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\tau^k}{k!}\frac{\partial^kg}{\partial t^k}\frac{\tau^j}{j!}\frac{\partial^jh}{\partial t^j}
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\tau^k}{k!}\frac{\partial^kg}{\partial t^k}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\tau^j}{j!}\frac{\partial^jh}{\partial t^j}
\\
&=&
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\tau^k}{k!}\frac{\partial^kg}{\partial t^k}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\tau^j}{j!}\frac{\partial^jh}{\partial t^j}\right)
\\
&=&
\left(\exp \left( \tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) g\right)\left(\exp \left( \tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) h\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Just to clarify, the function that you define in your answer would work the same way if $f(x,t)$ were written as a product? So the following is true?
$$  \exp \left( \tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) \left[ g(x,t)h(x,t)\right] = g(x,t+ \tau)h(x,t+ \tau) $$

Comment: @Chem-man17: Yes. How could the result depend on how the function is *written*?

Comment: Ok, I constructed some toy examples and I think I see what you mean. Thanks! One final question, is it correct to say the following?
$$ \exp\left(\tau\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\,g(x,t)h(x,t) = g(x,t + \tau)h(x,t + \tau) =  \
\left[ \exp\left(\tau\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\,g(x,t)\right] \left[ \exp\left(\tau\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\,h(x,t) \right]$$

Comment: @Chem-man17: Well, the left-hand side is a bit ambiguous; above and in the question you disambiguated it with brackets, that was clearer notation. Here it's not entirely clear whether the exponential operator is being applied to the entire product or just to $g$. Other than that, it's correct (assuming, as we have been all along, that the functions are sufficiently well-behaved, i.e. they have a Fourier series at $t$ and its radius of convergence is greater than $\tau$).

Comment: Yeah, in my comment I meant the operator to act on the product of $g(x,t)h(x,t)$ together. It's so non intuitive to me that the operator would just split up like that. But it works out for the few cases I tried. It would give me more peace of mind if I could do the expansion, group terms and prove the equivalence. 
Thanks a lot! Accepting your answer.

Comment: @Chem-man17: Well, peace of mind is a valuable thing, so I added what I assume you mean by "doing the expansion" to the answer. Promise me that you'll never actually use this and instead focus on simpler things like products of functions being functions :-)

Comment: I'm not supposed to use comments for thanks but I would be remiss if I didn't. Thanks a lot, this helps so much!